# Crystal Report viwer Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, report

I am New In Crystal Report. I created One Crystal report in asp.net with backend c# and add charts int it.everything is gng properly but when i run application . it shows only  report viwer bar and gives error that the

The Report Application Server Failed

Please Help Me Out.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

There's not much detail in your question.

Anyway I found an interesting post on MSDN : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vscrystalreports/thread/a6e12469-2bf1-4c4f-b291-0cf06465b740.

Many solutions were provided there, since we have no more information from you, try them all.

- Temporary files : delete the temporary files from temp folder. And restart the system.

Cause : it happened when system was abnormal shutdown. Crystal report has temp report files in Temp folder which were not washed out. Due to this it caused Load Report failed error.

- Registry : change the PrintJobLimit from 75 to -1 in;

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Crystal Decisions\10.2\Report Application Server\Server\PrintJobLimit

- Programmatically :

If you haven't found a solution for this yet, here is the last one.  This C# example works perfectly. Here a snippit of the code below.  It highlights the stuff that wasn't readily apparent from anything else one could read on the web.

```
private ReportDocument CrystalRpt;
    //Declaring these here and disposing in the Page_Unload event was the key.  Then the only other issue was the
    // limitations of Crystal 11 and simultaneous access to the rpt file.  I make a temp copy of the file and use that in the
    // method.  Then I delete the temp file in the unload event.

    private ReportDocument mySubRepDoc;
    private ReportClass ReportObject;
    private string tmpReportName;

    protected void Page_UnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
Try
{
            CrystalReportViewer1.Dispose();
            CrystalReportViewer1 = null;
            CrystalRpt.Close();
            CrystalRpt.Dispose();
            CrystalRpt = null;
            mySubRepDoc.Close();
            mySubRepDoc.Dispose();
            mySubRepDoc = null;
            ReportObject.Close();
            ReportObject.Dispose();
            ReportObject = null;
            GC.Collect();
            File.Delete(tmpReportName);

}
catch
{ ...Error Handler }
    }



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrystalRpt = new ReportDocument();
        ConnectionInfo CrystalConn = new ConnectionInfo();
        TableLogOnInfo tblLogonInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ReportObject = new ReportClass();

        TableLogOnInfo CrystalLogonInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ParameterField CrystalParameter = new ParameterField();
        ParameterFields CrystalParameters = new ParameterFields();
        ParameterDiscreteValue CrystalParameterDV = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

        TableLogOnInfo ConInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        SubreportObject mySubReportObject;
        mySubRepDoc = new ReportDocument();

        //Report name is sent in querystring.
        string ReportName = Request.QueryString["ReportName"];

        // I did this because Crystal 11 only supports 3 simultaneous users accessing the report and 
        // we have up to 60 at any time.  This copies the actual rpt file to a temp rpt file.  The temp rpt
        // file is used and then is deleted in the Page_Unload event

        Random MyRandomNumber = new Random();
        tmpReportName = ReportName.Replace(".rpt", "").Replace(".ltr", "") + MyRandomNumber.Next().ToString() +".rpt";
        File.Copy(ReportName, tmpReportName, true);

        CrystalRpt.Load(tmpReportName);
```

Comment: The registry solution is the best one